# How to get the HTML format string from a TextField in JSFL

Tags: html, flash, properties, formatting, jsfl

How can I get access to the *.htmlText property of a TextField on the timeline? I'm looking for something that can return all the formatting information just like it does in **ActionScript 3.0** at runtime.

Example:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
    <P ALIGN="CENTER">
        <FONT FACE="Verdana"
              SIZE="64"
              COLOR="#FF0000"
              LETTERSPACING="0"
              KERNING="1">
            <B>This is a </B>
            <FONT COLOR="#000000">
                <B>bold</B>
                <FONT SIZE="33">
                    <B>example</B>
                </FONT>
            </FONT>
        </FONT>
    </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
```

Comment: Coming up with a solution... yet again! Will post the solution when it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to write it up from scratch! So here it is:

```
/*

  Usage:
    var labelHTML = HTMLUtils.convertToHTML( someLabel );
    trace("The HTML of the selected label in the IDE is:\n" + labelHTML);

*/

var _TAG_TEMPLATE = "<$0$1>$2</$0>";

HTMLUtils = {

    convertToHTML: function(pTextField) {
        var runs =  pTextField.textRuns,
            run, content, output,
            leading;

        this.rootNode = new HTMLElement("ROOT");

        for (var r=0, rLen=runs.length; r<rLen; r++) {
            run = runs[r];
            content = run.characters;

            this.convertAttrsToHTML(run.textAttrs, content);
        }

        this.currentTextFormat = null;

        return this.rootNode.toHTML(true);
    },

    convertAttrsToHTML: function(pTextAttrs, pContent) {
        var contentLines =  pContent.split("\r");
        var masterFontNode;

        if(!this.currentTextFormat) {
            masterFontNode = this.createNewTextFormat( pTextAttrs );
        } else {
            masterFontNode =    this.currentTextFormat.childAt(0,0);
        }

        var fontNode = new HTMLFont();
        fontNode.addNode( new HTMLText( pContent ) );
        this.assignFontAttributes( fontNode, pTextAttrs );

        masterFontNode.addNode( fontNode );

        //trace( pTextAttrs.toTrace() );

        this.currentTextFormat.attributes.leading = String(pTextAttrs.lineSpacing);
        this.currentTextFormat.children[0].attributes.align = String(pTextAttrs.alignment);

        if(contentLines.length>1) {
            this.currentTextFormat = null; //
        }
    },

    createNewTextFormat: function( pTextAttrs ) {
        this.currentTextFormat =    new HTMLElement("TEXTFORMAT");
        this.rootNode.addNode(this.currentTextFormat);

        var paragraph = new HTMLElement("P");
        this.currentTextFormat.addNode( paragraph );

        var fontNode =  new HTMLFont();
        paragraph.addNode( fontNode );

        this.assignFontAttributes( fontNode, pTextAttrs );

        return fontNode;
    },

    assignFontAttributes: function( pFontNode, pTextAttrs ) {
        pFontNode.attributes.face = String(pTextAttrs.face);
        pFontNode.attributes.size = String(pTextAttrs.size);
        pFontNode.attributes.letterSpacing = String(pTextAttrs.letterSpacing);
        pFontNode.attributes.color = String(pTextAttrs.fillColor);
        pFontNode.isBold =      pTextAttrs.bold;
        pFontNode.isItalic =    pTextAttrs.italic;
    }
};


HTMLElement =   Class.extend({
    init: function( pName ) {
        this.name = pName;
        this.children = [];
        this.parent = null;
        this.attributes =   {};
    },

    clone: function(pOnlyThis) {
        var theClone =  new HTMLElement( this.name );
        theClone.attributes = this.attributes.copy();
        return theClone;
    },

    addNode: function(pNode) {
        this.children.push(pNode);
        pNode.parent = this;

        return pNode;
    },

    childAt: function() {
        var current = this;
        for (var a=0, aLen=arguments.length; a<aLen; a++) {
            var index = arguments[a];

            current = current.children[index];
        }

        return current;
    },

    parentOfType: function(pName) {
        var currentNode =   this.parent;
        while(currentNode && currentNode.name!=pName) {
            currentNode = currentNode.parent;
        }

        return currentNode;
    },

    childrenHTML: function() {
        var theHTML =   "";
        var theChildren =   this.children,
            theChild;

        for (var c=0, cLen=theChildren.length; c<cLen; c++) {
            theChild =  theChildren[c];
            theHTML += theChild.toHTML();
        }

        return theHTML;
    },

    toHTML: function(pInnerOnly) {
        var theHTML =   this.childrenHTML();

        if(pInnerOnly) {
            return theHTML;
        }

        var theAttributes = [];
        var theAttrProperties = this.attributes.getProperties();

        for(var a=0, aLen=theAttrProperties.length; a<aLen; a++) {
            var attr =      theAttrProperties[a];
            var attrBIG =   attr.toUpperCase();
            var attrValue = this.attributes[attr];
            theAttributes.push(attrBIG + "=\"" + attrValue + "\"");
        }

        if(theAttributes.length==0) {
            theAttributes = "";
        } else {
            theAttributes = " " + theAttributes.join(" ");
        }

        return _TAG_TEMPLATE.inject(this.name, theAttributes, theHTML);
    }
});

HTMLFont = HTMLElement.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super("FONT");
    },
    toHTML: function(pInnerOnly) {
        var parentFont = this.parentOfType("FONT");
        if(parentFont) {
            //Find differences in attributes:
            var parentAttrs =   parentFont.attributes;
            var myAttrs =       this.attributes;

            var theAttrProperties = myAttrs.getProperties();
            var differentAttrs =    [];

            for (var a=0, aLen=theAttrProperties.length; a<aLen; a++) {
                var attr =          theAttrProperties[a];
                var attrValue =     myAttrs[attr];
                var parentValue =   parentAttrs[attr];

                if(parentValue==null || parentValue==attrValue) {
                    continue;
                }

                differentAttrs.push( attr.toUpperCase() + "=\"" + attrValue + "\"");
            }

            var theHTML =   this.childrenHTML();

            if(this.isBold) { theHTML = "<B>" + theHTML + "</B>"; }
            if(this.isItalic) { theHTML =   "<I>" + theHTML + "</I>"; }

            if(differentAttrs.length==0) {
                return theHTML;
            } else {
                differentAttrs = " " + differentAttrs.join(" ");
            }

            return _TAG_TEMPLATE.inject(this.name, differentAttrs, theHTML);
        }
        return this._super(pInnerOnly);
    }
});

HTMLText =  HTMLElement.extend({
    init: function( pContent ) {
        this._super("TEXT");
        this._content = pContent;
    },
    toHTML: function() {
        return this._content;
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** For the sections that are defining **Classes** and **extending** them, you can obtain that functionality from this site: **[John Resig's Inheritance Script for JavaScript - based on Prototype](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)**. It's a great script to have at the core of any JavaScript based language, it simplifies OOP so much!

Comment: There may be some dependencies I've forgotten to include, but basically for any object iterations (ex: go through 'attributes' properties), in JavaScript you can simply do a for-in loop where the keys will be the property name, and object[key] is the value.

Comment: Did you find anything in Java for the same functionality?

Comment: It's been a while since I touched this code / let alone dealt with HTML text in Flash, AND Java :( sorry don't know if any similar solution exists for it.